# Exporting an ndarray containing real numbers as real and complex numbers as complex format using DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I am exporting a datafile in CSV format and using panda's DataFrame for it. The data file contains real numbers as well as complex numbers. When the data is exported, all kinds of numbers are in complex format even a zero value is also shown in complex format '''0.000000+0.000000j''' How can I export the file so that real numbers won't be in a complex format?
FYI: I have created the real and complex numbers separately. Here is the code,

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    L=2;
    Lmax = 9
    data = np.zeros((Lmax, Lmax))
    com_data = np.zeros((Lmax, Lmax), dtype = np.complex128)
    all_data_row = np.zeros((Lmax, Lmax))

    for a in range (1, 4):
        for b in range (1, 4):
            if (a == 3 or b ==3) and (a != b):
                for L1 in range(1, Lmax+1):
                    for L2 in range(1, Lmax+1):
                        com_data[L1-1, L2-1] = DYu(a,b,L1,L,L2)
                ar = np.concatenate((ar, com_data),axis=1)
        
            else:
                for L1 in range(1, Lmax+1):
                    for L2 in range(1, Lmax+1):
                        data[L1-1, L2-1] = DYu(a,b,L1,L,L2)
                if b == 1:
                    ar = np.concatenate((all_data_row, data),axis=1)
                else:
                    ar = np.concatenate((ar, data),axis=1)
    
            data_array = pd.DataFrame(ar)
            data_array = data_array.drop(data_array.iloc[:,0:10], axis=1) 
    data_array.to_csv(f'folder_directory\\L = {L}, a = {a}, b = {b}.csv')
```

Here DYu is a long function that is generating complex values if the condition
if (a == 3 or b ==3) and (a != b):
is met.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have got the answer. I am just posting it here in case someone needs it. The key is to separate the real and complex values at the time of forming `data_array`

```
real_part = np.round(data_array . real, 10)
enter code hereimag_part = np.round(data_array . imag, 10)
data_array_real = pd.DataFrame(real_part)
data_array_real = data_array_real.drop(data_array_real.iloc[:, 0:Lmax], axis=0)
data_array_real = data_array_real.drop(data_array_real.iloc[:, 0:Lmax], axis=1)
data_array_imag = pd.DataFrame(imag_part)
data_array_imag = data_array_imag.drop(data_array_imag.iloc[:, 0:Lmax], axis=0)
data_array_imag = data_array_imag.drop(data_array_imag.iloc[:, 0:Lmax], axis=1)
data_array_real.to_csv(dirName_M + "/" + fileName_M_real , index=False, header=False)
data_array_imag.to_csv(dirName_M + "/" + fileName_M_imag , index=False, header=False)
```